# change ftp password using php and send them to mail running cron

Tags: php, ftp

I have websites hosted in godaddy . i want change ftp password using php weekly and mail all ftp passwords to email id using cron. My websites are hosted on godaddy shared server

Comment: i want to change all ftp passwords using PHP weekly , not going to cpanel of my hosting

Answer (score 0):

php is not required for what you ask, you could make cron run a bash script to change the pass of X user, that depends on what Ftp server software your hosting server uses, u can send a mail using php or use mail command...

Comment: how to change password for ftp user using bash script